# С помощью какого свойства можно расположить блоки таким образом как на рисунке (имеется ввиду что слева картинка, а справа блок разделён на 2 части)

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста с расположением. Я пыталась сделать с помощью grid, но получилось так, как на второй картинке. Линии я тоже вставляла, но из-за того, что они уходили вправо я их просто убрала.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с помощью `flex` или `grid`, что вам больше нравится

Comment: Если используете bootstrap, то **col-3** на каждый блок и border на нужные блоки, а так в целом, на втором варианте у вас неплохо получилось, добавить padding, добавить border и в целом всё в порядке, только вопрос в том, как это будет смотреться на мобильных устройствах.

Comment: `но получилось так, как на второй картинке` а что именно во втором варианте не устраивает то? да и саму верстку добавить сюда в вопрос не помешало бы(правее кнопки "код" есть сниппет удобства ради)